# is using first form of verb for past correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, writing

I was reviewing homework copy of my son. On a place he wrote:

> One week before I went to the dentist to check my teeth.

(In a letter he was telling to his friend what he did last week)

His teacher checked the copy and edited the line as:

> One week before I go to the dentist to check my teeth.

I m not a native English speaker but to me this was a wrong edit. Can you please guide if my understanding is correct or not ? Is there any othere error in this line ? Please help.

Comment: One week before/earlier.  neither went nor go. You use the past perfect.  One week before I had gone.....

Comment: To proofread proofreading done by a teacher, we'd need more context. The sentences before or after that sentence could give us more clues why the teacher chose to correct it that way. A possible reason could be: the sentence might've actually been a fragment, which is okay in creative writing, and it probably made more sense to read it as "One week before I do something in this story, something happens", as opposed to "One week ago, I did something".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are nearly right grammatically, they just have different meanings. For the first example, a better way of saying this would be:

> *One week ago* OR *Last week*, I went to the dentist to check my teeth

The above sentence means that you went to the dentist a week before now. However, if you wanted to specify it was *before the weekend he is talking about*, you would say something like:

> *The previous week* OR *One week earlier*, I had been to the dentist to check my teeth

Although I don't think the above example quite fits the context you gave.

As for the example his teacher corrected it to, this is also correct, however it means something different to what you're trying to say. Take this example:

> It's only one week before I go to the dentist to check my teeth!

This is talking about an event in the future - so you are going to go to the dentist in a week's time.

Both examples are correct grammatically, however you are writing about *what you did last weekend*, so "went" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to James Wirth's great answer, your second example is not a sentence.

> One week (subject) before I go to the dentist to check my teeth
>   (adverbial clause).

There is no verb in the sentence. In other words, you need a [predicate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predicate) in order to make it a sentence. For example:

> One week (subject) **is left** (predicate) before (or until) I go to the dentist to check my teeth (adverbial clause).

As @DamkerngT commented, there is no way we could read the mind of your son's teacher and we need more context. However, one thing for sure is (s)he made a mistake as the corrected sentence can never describe "what he did last week".